# OBJC_CLASS_$_GSDK_GTMLogBasicFormatter", referenced from: objc-class-ref in iOS objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, ipad

I Removed the StartApp sdk and added GoogleAd sdk it shows like

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GSDK_GTMLogBasicFormatter", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in FirebaseCrash(FCRSystemLogger_f6f509c6b037cc95a2a7c093bb001dda.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GSDK_GTMLogNoFilter", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in FirebaseCrash(FCRSystemLogger_f6f509c6b037cc95a2a7c093bb001dda.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GSDK_GTMLogger", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in FirebaseCrash(uploader_3642662f425997146581ee52249eee05.o)
      objc-class-ref in FirebaseCrash(FCRSystemLogger_f6f509c6b037cc95a2a7c093bb001dda.o)
```

Using Xcode 14.1 and iOS 15.7.

When I removed StartApp sdk and Added GoogleAdSdk now facing like this error

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GSDK_GTMLogBasicFormatter", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in FirebaseCrash(FCRSystemLogger_f6f509c6b037cc95a2a7c093bb001dda.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GSDK_GTMLogNoFilter", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in FirebaseCrash(FCRSystemLogger_f6f509c6b037cc95a2a7c093bb001dda.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GSDK_GTMLogger", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in FirebaseCrash(uploader_3642662f425997146581ee52249eee05.o)
      objc-class-ref in FirebaseCrash(FCRSystemLogger_f6f509c6b037cc95a2a7c093bb001dda.o)
```

Using 14.1 Xcode and iOS 15.7

Comment: Are you using CocoaPods?

Comment: Removed unwanted sdk and installing the cocoapods what you want the issue will gone. fixed. hanks man...!

Comment: You are right removed unwanted sdk after that need to install sdk what you want after that it will be working fine. thanks for your reply :)